# How to produce constant output in a Terminal window?

Tags: terminal

Like when you do `brew install wget` or `mysqld restart` I want some lines of information constantly run through my terminal window. Is there maybe something I can monitor or any stream of information I can jump in? Is it maybe possible to watch the activity monitor processes in the terminal?

Why would I want to have that? Because it looks super cool when you have that Matrix-like code running over your monitor. And I could need that for some home movie scenes.

Comment: Matrix-like (aka top down) or similar to brew (horizontally) are two different things, what exactly are you looking for? And did you already ask the mighty Google for an answer?

Comment: Quite different, you are right! Now that I looked at it again, Matrix-like does much more look like a toy or a screensaver than a productive tool running. Homebrew-like would be much better. I found some kid's tutorials on youtube about how to let random numbers run thorugh the terminal but that doesn't look very professional.

Comment: Download source code of a major program and compile it in your terminal, that would "look" *professional*, anything else is pretty much just noise unless it's useful output like watching some logs (as @Matteo suggests).  Of course, compiling also takes major resources.

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21347/output-hollywood-hacker-scene-from-a-shell

Comment: Also related, [here's an interesting page from one of the guys who worked on Tron where he talks about how they made the computer looking stuff for the movie](http://jtnimoy.net/workviewer.php?q=178).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pulling ideas from this [unix.stackexchange.com Q&A about generating "hollywood" style terminal output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21347/output-hollywood-hacker-scene-from-a-shell).

### The Slow Type

This script produces that delayed typing like effect you see in movies. Where the computer prints things in the terminal at some really awful and slow rate.

Save the following to a file named `hollywood`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
    length="${#line}"
    bol=1
    for (( offset = 0 ; offset < length ; offset++ )); do
        char="${line:offset:1}"
        printf '%s' "$char"
        if (( bol )) && [[ "$char" == " " ]]; then
            continue
        fi
        bol=0
        sleep 0.05
    done

    if (( length == 0 )); then
        sleep 0.$(( RANDOM % 3 + 2 ))
    else
        sleep 0.$(( RANDOM % 7 + 3 ))
    fi

    printf '\n'
done
```

Set execute permissions on the file `hollywood`:

```
chmod +x hollywood
```

And then pipe it the output from `dmesg` to give it a large chunk of snazzy looking text to slowly print on the screen:

```
dmesg | hollywood
```

### The Hex Dump

This dumps hex data to the screen. Looks impressive but is largely unintelligible to the masses.

```
hexdump -C /dev/urandom | GREP_COLOR='1;32' grep --color=auto 'ca fe'
```

### The Matrix

Numbers. Numbers everywhere.

```
LC_CTYPE=C tr -c "[:digit:]" " " < /dev/urandom | dd cbs=$COLUMNS conv=unblock | GREP_COLOR="1;32" grep --color "[^ ]"
```

Unfortunately, with that one there isn't a good way to control the speed.

There's a better version of this available view Homebrew called [cmatrix](http://www.asty.org/cmatrix/). You can install and run it with:

```
brew install cmatrix
cmatrix
```

Comment: Great solution. The Hex Dump line should end on ' though. I tried editing it but Stackexchange expects at least 6 characters to be changed. Why?  —Unfortunately "tr -c "[:digit:]" " " < /dev/urandom" produces a "tr: Illegal byte sequence" error for me on OS X 10.11.6.

Comment: @AlexIxeras good catch. fixed.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why "tr -c "[:digit:]" " " < /dev/urandom" results in error "tr: Illegal byte sequence"?

Comment: @AlexIxeras ah, yes. `/dev/urandom` is outputting non-ASCII characters. I've fixed the example line so `tr` just ignores the non-ASCII characters and doesn't complain.

Answer (score 6):

If you have some files that are growing you can use `tail -f`. For example

```
 $ tail -f /var/log/system.log
```

There are several terminal tools similar to activity monitor, for example top (delivered with OS X) and htop (you will have to install it with MacPorts or Homebrew).

You could also download the sources of a large software package (e.g., gcc, OpenOffice) and then compile it. This will usually generate a lot of output on the console.

You could also generate huge directory listings

```
$ ls -lRt
```

or `find` (the second one will delay each line by one second)

```
$ find .
$ find . -print -exec sleep 1 \;
```

Comment: `top` is quite nice, some characters are constantly changing. But has no lines runnning over the screen. Downloading sources, I find it's too much data for only fun.

Comment: Combine a `cat /var/log/system.log` with a pipe to the slow type script below and you'd have a nice, continuous flow of Terminal output.

Answer (score 4):

The `matrix command`:

```
od -c /dev/random
```

Read carefully, at a given time you will see the secret key.

Comment: Perfect answer!

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
while sleep 1; do
    t=$(( RANDOM % 80 ))
    for ((i=0; i < $t; i++)); do
        echo -n '*'
        sleep 1
    done
    echo
done
```

might do the trick. Change the length of the sleeps for different speeds and replace the `*` with whatever you want (even `$(( RANDOM % 10 ))` for varying numbers).

Answer (score 0):

You can try `tcpdump` in Terminal. It lists the connections your computer makes through the active network interfaces. When you're having any network activity it will show running data on the screen.